# In what system are coordinates from the ST_AsMVT PostGIS function

Tags: python, postgis, mapbox, vector-tiles

I have a table (`records_addressvalue`) in my PostgreSQL database with a `geom` column (`geom`) with `srid=3857`. I have some rows in there, and I'm querying the database to generate MVT tiles. I'm following [this documentation](https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/dynamic-vector-tiles-from-postgis). The resulting query for a specific tile, for instance, the tile `/0/0/0` (with the format `/{x}/{y}/{z}`), is:

```sql
WITH bounds AS (
    SELECT ST_Segmentize(
                   ST_MakeEnvelope(-20037508.3427892, -20037508.3427892, 20037508.3427892, 20037508.3427892, 3857),
                   10018754.1713946)        AS geom,
           ST_Segmentize(
                   ST_MakeEnvelope(-20037508.3427892, -20037508.3427892, 20037508.3427892, 20037508.3427892, 3857),
                   10018754.1713946)::box2d AS b2d
),
     mvtgeom AS (
         SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(t.geom, 3857), bounds.b2d) AS geom,
                original_address
         FROM records_addressvalue t,
              bounds
         WHERE ST_Intersects(t.geom, ST_Transform(bounds.geom, 3857))
     )
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom.*)
FROM mvtgeom
```

That returns an MVT with data, that you need to decode according to the specification. You can do that in Python with the following code:

```py
import mapbox_vector_tile
mapbox_vector_tile.decode(result)
```

That returns me a JSON with a lot of things. You can check [the full JSON here](https://gist.github.com/antoniogamizbadger/f57a1e5b69144fa849b15ababec95b2e). Between those fields, we have the key `features`, where have the points inside that tile. They have the following format:

```json
{
    "geometry":{
       "type":"Point",
       "coordinates":[
          1208,
          2556
       ]
    },
    "properties":{
       "original_address":"11919 Jamaica Ave, Jamaica, NY 11418, EE. UU."
    },
    "id":0,
    "type":1
}
```

As you can see, there's a key called `coordinates`. My doubt is, in what reference system are those coordinates? What does mean `[1208, 2556]`? I'm trying to use those coordinates to draw some markers on my Google Map, but I cannot find how to interpret those coordinates. Any idea or docs I can read about?

Comment: I wouldn't use MVT to try to draw on Google Maps - KML or GeoJSON would be better

Comment: Those coordinates reference *tile coordinate space*, with a tile having a default extent of 4096 x 4096 units. In each axis orientation, the global Web Mercator (EPSG:3857) extent is divided by `2^{z}` tiles, and the resulting range of Web Mercator meters of a single tile again divided by the tile extent (4096).

Comment: Read https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/specification/#encoding-geometry. For locating 1208,2556 you must know that 0/0/0 tile covers the whole world and that the size of the coordinate space of your tile is 4096x4096.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this info! @Ian Turton why would you not use MVT? Can you reference some docs about it? I have been reading about GeoJSON and the main disadvantage I saw it's that you need to send all the information together. I have not yet tried KML but I will give it a look.

Comment: @user30184 oh I see! thanks! Why is the coordinate space of my tile 4096x4096? Is that set in the code? or it's an arbitrary number?

Comment: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVTGeom.html `extent is the tile extent in tile coordinate space as defined by the specification. If NULL it will default to 4096.`

Comment: Great, thanks!!!!!!! That's really helpful. Could post that as an answer so I mark it as accepted? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connecting MVT vector tile coordinates 1208,2556 in tile 0/0/0 into real world coordinates requires a few steps

1. What is the the tiling schema. The most common schema is Google maps compatible (find more information from https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames). There are other tiling schemas and they can be used with MVT so it is not safe to presume that every MVT is using the Google schema. Your 0/0/0 tile is using the Google schema and it covers the whole valid area of the EPSG:3856 coordinate system that is "World between 85.06°S and 85.06°N". The projected bounds are -20026376.39 -20048966.10
   20026376.39 20048966.10.
2. Coordinates in the MVT tile are connected to tile coordinate space. Read the details from https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/specification/#encoding-geometry. Coordinate 1208,2556 is 1208 steps to the right and 2556 steps down from the top left corner of the tile. The projected coordinates of the top left corner are -20026376.39E, N20026376.39N in EPSG:3857, but we do not know what it the size of the step yet.
3. The extent of each MVT tile is by default 4096x4096 but it can be different. Clients that use MVT tiles can check the real extent from the .proto file. Specification of the proto file is in https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/blob/master/2.1/vector_tile.proto. PostGIS creates MVT tiles by using the default extent but it can be controlled with the "extent" option https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVT.html.

> **extent** is the tile extent in screen space as defined by the specification. Default is 4096.

Now you know where the tile is located on the surface of the Earth, the projected coordinates of the top left corner of the tile, the size of steps used in MVT, and you can resolve to location of point `1208, 2556`.

Comment: Hi again, @user30184, I have seen a parameter called `y_coord_down` in the python library. After reading the docs (https://github.com/tilezen/mapbox-vector-tile) I'm not sure what that means. I think I should set it to True because the y=0 is on the upper side and y=256 on the bottom (so it's going from up to down). Do you something about this?

Comment: Not really. It seems that the y order is controllable also other libraries https://gitter.im/geotrellis/geotrellis?at=5760862fb8ad3d5d7ee01626 and obviously the tile writer and reader must understand it in the same way.