# How to convert vector tile grid to geographic coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, vector-tiles, mapbox-vector-tile

I have decoded the mvt data using mapbox_vector_tile and it returns json. The coordinates are specified as: coordinates":[[1881,445],[1881,446],[1882,445]..... ]. And the extent is 4096. Is it possible to convert this coordinates to geographic coordinate.

Comment: Reference: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/411199/in-what-system-are-coordinates-from-the-st-asmvt-postgis-function